# Install and update failed because of access denied error on 'Code - Insiders.exe'

Tags: visual-studio-code

After a recent update, my VS Code Insiders system is trashed. It failed during the update and during an attempt to re-install the software. All attempts to remove or move the 'Microsoft VS Code Insiders' directory have failed. I am the administrator of the box in question and all attempts have run at that level. Even invoking the hidden administrator level. I tried using `takedown` and `icacls`. I have used `subancl` to no avail as well. As a result, I have a damaged system that can't be removed and which blocks installing a new system at that location (the vanilla folder, etc).

As near as I can tell, this is a result of the update crash. As evidence, the file icon no longer displays and the error messages, one saying access denied and the other saying no such path or file, indicate something broken somewhere.

**Update:** This includes running as elevated administrator, up to and including TrustedInstaller…

Does someone know of a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled across '*an answer*', certainly not an official one though. As it turns out the file was so bit damaged that while it invoked an annoying selection of error messages, it did not register as a file! In short, when I upgraded drive C:\, it did not come along for the ride. Serendipity strikes again…